# Unencoded < char error after running ionic cordova prepare ios

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm updating my old Ionic 1 project which was actually working 2 months ago.

The error that I'm getting after running `ionic cordova prepare ios` is:

```
Error: Unencoded <
Line: 1
Column: 2
Char: <
    at error (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:666:10)
    at strictFail (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:692:7)
    at SAXParser.write (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/elementtree/node_modules/sax/lib/sax.js:1080:13)
    at XMLParser.feed (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/elementtree/lib/parsers/sax.js:48:15)
    at ElementTree.parse (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:271:10)
    at Object.parse (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/elementtree/lib/elementtree.js:584:8)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/@ionic/cli-utils/lib/cordova/config.js:35:28)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/Users/nikola/DEV/myFirstIonicProject/node_modules/ionic/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:104:62)
    at <anonymous>
```

Any ideas or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those 'Ionic 1 moments' where the solution was not in the error message but in taking a close look at `config.xml` file and making sure there are no extra characters there.

In my case, I had an extra line at the end of the file. Why this was throwing the build off, I'm not sure.

Either way, hope this helps someone. [This](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/2902) official thread was also useful for nailing down this 'bug'.